# How to show local html into WebView?

Tags: android

I got a html in assets folder:

```
<h2>Hi</h2>
```

Tried to show it in WebView:

```
public class ContentWebActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content_web);

    final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/webview.html");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

}
```

}

Run emulator and got an error:

```
The webpage at file:///android_assets/webview.html could not be loaded becouse:
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be "**file:///android_asset/webview.html**", you actually used **android_assets**

```java
final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/webview.html");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thank, did not noticed this `s`.